# Eclipse @Observes in @Stateless bean compile error

Tags: eclipse, ejb, java-ee-6, observer-pattern, stateless

I have a ListenerImpl which purpose it is to handle Events Asynchronously.
to achieve this I use the following method.

```
    @Asynchronous
    public void handle(@Observes MonitorEvent pEvent){
       //dostuff 
    }
```

The class itself is annotated with @Stateless.

Now Eclipse gives the following error: 
handle observer method is only allowed in a managed bean class, session bean class, or an extension class.

Someone knows whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem to convert the component into an ejb-module instead of a utility module.